# how to convert existing table into same format in longtable?

Tags: longtable

My `longtable` need to spread into 3 pages. I have reviewed many past answers on `longtable` and tried without success. I need to post here for suggestion. Below is my existing Latex code:

```
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \tiny
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \caption{State-of-the-art based on the taxonomy.}
    %\label{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l|p{7.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}}
        %\hline 
        Item& Sota & DummyA & DummyB & DummyC\\
        \hline 
        \hline 
        A & ASota & AA & AB&AC\\
        \hline 
        B & BSota& BA & BB & BC\\
        \hline
        C & CSota& CA& CB &CC\\
        \hline
        D & DSota& DA& DB &DC \\
        \hline  
        E & ESota& EA& EB &EC \\
        \hline 
        F & FSota& FA& FB &FC \\
        \hline
        G & GSota& GA& GB &GC \\
        \hline
        H & HSota& HA& HB &HC \\
        \hline
        I & ISota& IA& IB &IC \\
        \hline
        J & JSota& JA& JB &JC \\
        \hline
        K & KSota& KA& KB &KC \\
        \hline
        L & LSota& LA& LB &LC \\
        \hline
        M & MSota& MA& MB &MC \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you've tried. E.g., what does "without success" mean in the present context?

Comment: That is I change the tabular into longtable or tabularX and the caption into longtable environment , remove table* ...the results did not ends well. I think I got problems in translating !hdbp and the tabular arguments into longtable arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When converting from a `table`/`tabular` pair of environments to a (single) `longtable` environment, be sure to define the table's headers and footers, via `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot` directives.

If you need to change the font size of the `longtable` (say, to `\tiny`), do encase the entire `longtable` environment in a pair of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements. This'll keep the scope of `\tiny` local.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begingroup 
%\tiny %% is this really necessary?
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize,skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{longtable}{@{}l|p{7.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}@{}}
%% headers and footers

\caption{State-of-the-art based on the taxonomy.}
\label{table}\\
Item & Sota & DummyA & DummyB & DummyC \\
\hline \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\em Table \ref{table}, continued}\\[1ex]
Item& Sota & DummyA & DummyB & DummyC\\
\hline\hline
\endhead

\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\em (Continued on following page)}\\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of longtable env.
        A & ASota& AA& AB &AC \\
        \hline 
        B & BSota& BA& BB &BC \\
        \hline
        C & CSota& CA& CB &CC \\
        \hline
        D & DSota& DA& DB &DC \\
        \hline  
        E & ESota& EA& EB &EC \\
        \hline 
        F & FSota& FA& FB &FC \\
        \hline
        G & GSota& GA& GB &GC \\
        \hline
        H & HSota& HA& HB &HC \\
        \hline
        I & ISota& IA& IB &IC \\
        \hline
        J & JSota& JA& JB &JC \\
        \hline
        K & KSota& KA& KB &KC \\
        \hline
        L & LSota& LA& LB &LC \\
        \hline
        M & MSota& MA& MB &MC \\
        \hline
        A & ASota& AA& AB &AC \\
        \hline 
        B & BSota& BA& BB &BC \\
        \hline
        C & CSota& CA& CB &CC \\
        \hline
        D & DSota& DA& DB &DC \\
        \hline  
        E & ESota& EA& EB &EC \\
        \hline 
        F & FSota& FA& FB &FC \\
        \hline
        G & GSota& GA& GB &GC \\
        \hline
        H & HSota& HA& HB &HC \\
        \hline
        I & ISota& IA& IB &IC \\
        \hline
        J & JSota& JA& JB &JC \\
        \hline
        K & KSota& KA& KB &KC \\
        \hline
        L & LSota& LA& LB &LC \\
        \hline
        M & MSota& MA& MB &MC \\
        \hline
        A & ASota& AA &AB &AC \\
        \hline 
        B & BSota& BA &BB &BC \\
        \hline
        C & CSota& CA& CB &CC \\
        \hline
        D & DSota& DA& DB &DC \\
        \hline  
        E & ESota& EA& EB &EC \\
        \hline 
        F & FSota& FA& FB &FC \\
        \hline
        G & GSota& GA& GB &GC \\
        \hline
        H & HSota& HA& HB &HC \\
        \hline
        I & ISota& IA& IB &IC \\
        \hline
        J & JSota& JA& JB &JC \\
        \hline
        K & KSota& KA& KB &KC \\
        \hline
        L & LSota& LA& LB &LC \\
        \hline
        M & MSota& MA& MB &MC \\
        \hline 
        F & FSota& FA& FB &FC \\
        \hline
        G & GSota& GA& GB &GC \\
        \hline
        H & HSota& HA& HB &HC \\
        \hline
        I & ISota& IA& IB &IC \\
        \hline
        J & JSota& JA& JB &JC \\
        \hline
        K & KSota& KA& KB &KC \\
        \hline
        L & LSota& LA& LB &LC \\
        \hline
        M & MSota& MA& MB &MC \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico for very prompt response! I will try out first and let you know.

Comment: I tried and it spread out into 30 pages instead of 3 pages. Then I turn on tiny and it reduce into 6 pages. I think I need to reduce the line spacing as my Sota column is full of texts, any idea? Thx.

Comment: @CaseyYeow - Without knowledge of what's in the "sota" column, it's not really possible to give specific advice. My answer uses single-spacing; is your document set to use wide line-spacing? If so, how is it set up?

Comment: You see, comparing to my original, the new line spacing(you are using single spacing) for "tiny" is much wider. Example of content in "Sota" column" : "HS-Relay/2013\cite{corallo2013high}-is a centralized, exclusive and high speed relaying network/system of peering nodes, which comprised of miners, exchanges and merchants. Its main aims are to scale up the blockchain by reducing the block propagation latency among miners as well as a fallback in time of Bitcoin main network failure." Regarding my document setting:

Comment: \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Useful for including code listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\SingleSpacing,
        columns=fullflexible,
        breaklines,breakatwhitespace}

Comment: @CaseyYeow - Unless you really have nothing but contempt for the readers of your document, don't use `\tiny` (or `\scriptsize`). `\footnotesize` (for text material) is the smallest size I'd dare spring on readers of my documents.

Comment: It is more natural to read the "tiny" in 3 pages instead of stretching out to 6 pages. I am just wondering, why in the same document setting, the original table & tabular codes have a narrower line spacing than that of longtable codings?

Comment: @CaseyYeow - I'm afraid I don't understand your question. There's can be little point in us arguing what is "more natural", is there? There must be a reason, though, for why `\scriptsize` and `\tiny` -- the text-mode equivalents of math-mode `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptstyle` directives, suitable for first- and second-level subscripts and superscripts -- are hardly ever chosen to represent running text.

Comment: Just ignore the "more natural" argument. My question is : how can a longtable coding/setting reproduce the same line spacing in "tiny" texts as that of the original tabular or table codings did? Thx.

Comment: @CaseyYeow - Since I don't have access to your code, I don't know if you are comparing equals or unequals. In particular, does the directive `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}`, which I included in my answer, apply to both environments or just to the `longtable`? If it applies only to the `longtable`, one shouldn't be surprised that the two environments exhibit different vertical spacing properties.

Comment: Another way, which is more feasible, is to increase the column width of Sota and reduce the other three columns' widths. Thanks.

Comment: @CaseyYeow - Obviously, only you can make that determination. For sure, I have no idea how wide the columns labeled "Dummy A", "Dummy B", and "Dummy C" should be; hence, I'm in no position to offer advice on this issue.

Comment: oic..sorry, the directive \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} only applies to the longtable.

Comment: Thanks Mico for your help, appreciate that. I think I can resolve this by choosing the best columns widths. Case considered closed.

Comment: @CaseyYeow - Glad you were able to find a suitable solution. Feel free to apply the "accept" check-mark if you believe this answer was helpful.

Comment: Where is the "accept" check-mark? Got to go. Later will apply that.